# what does the subscript operator mean in sort compare function?

Tags: sorting, compare, subscript-operator

```
struct pair{
    int first;
    int second;
}
vector<pair> v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](pair p1, pair p2){return p1.first < p2.first});
```

what does the `[](pair p1, pair p2){return p1.first < p2.first}` mean in sort? function pointer or anything else? I can't figure out the keywords to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a lambda expresion. See example below:

```
void abssort(float* x, unsigned n) {
    std::sort(x, x + n,
        // Lambda expression begins
        [](float a, float b) {
            return (std::abs(a) < std::abs(b));
        } // end of lambda expression
    );
}
```

2. reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx

the function that is being passed as a parameter does not have a "function name" - it is anonymous. This is a useful abstraction as all that is needed is the functionality that is being passed (the name does not matter).

Answer (score 2):

That's a [Lambda Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx) and the subscript operator is what introduces it. Lambda expressions were introduced in C++11.

I couldn't put it better than the MSDN article linked above which defines a lambda expression as follows:

> is a convenient way of defining an anonymous function object right at the location where it is invoked or passed as an argument to a function.